# How to extract the first non-Null match from a group of regexp matches in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a regular expression `(a)|(b)|(c)|(d)`. If I apply it to text `'foobar'` I get a match object

```
>>> compiled = re.compile('(a)|(b)|(c)|(d)')
>>> compiled.search('foobar').groups()
(None, 'b', None, None)
```

How do I extract the `'b'` from here? Or in general, how do I extract the first match from an unknown number of groups (can happen when the regexp was built dynamically)?

Comment: In this specific case you should use '(a|b|c|d)' so that you don't get multiple groups.

Comment: Well, that regexp is actually dynamically generated and it happens to be `(part1)|(part2)|...|(parti)|...|(partn)`. But thanks for useful remark!

Comment: How about just replace that from ")|(" to "|"?

Comment: If you have control over the generation, change it.  Returning each piece as "(?:partN)" still groups it, so you can then build up "((?:part1)|(?:part2)|...)". @SMark: You can't parse regex with either regex or string replace. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> g = (None, 'b', None, None)
>>> next(x for x in g if x is not None)
'b'

>>> g = (None, None, None)
>>> next((x for x in g if x is not None), "default")  # try this with filter :)
'default'

>>> g = (None, None, None)  # so you know what happens, and what you could catch
>>> next(x for x in g if x is not None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: Wow, that was difficult. Why Python doesn't have this as a builtin method for match group? Seems like a thing everyone invents over and over again hundreds and thousands of millions times. I am writing an angry letter to Python mailing list right now!

Comment: @bodacydo: I wouldn't mind if NoneType had a staticmethod named 'coalesce', but you can just as easily write the above single line into a function if this is difficult for you.  As to why it doesn't.. *\*shrug\** doesn't matter to me, because it doesn't and I have no control over changing it. :)

Comment: This is wrong thinking, everyone of us has control to change anything in open source projects!

Comment: @bodacydo: Okay, how about "It would take a lot of effort to get the maintainers of Python to do my bidding, this isn't an important issue for me, and I don't want to maintain it myself." :)

Answer (score 1):

```
reduce(lambda x, y : (x, y)[x is None], groups, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(lambda x : x is not None, groups)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> g = (None,'b',None,None)
>>> filter(None,g)
('b',)
>>> h = (None,None,None)
>>> filter(None,h)
()
```

Comment: Just remember it fails for empty strings, `g = (None, '')`.